# Atualizar arquivos de vários servidores com git automaticamente

Tags: git, github

Tenho um sistema que é utilizado por vários clientes e cada um possui seu servidor, sendo a maioria linux.

Gostaria de atualizar os arquivos via git automaticamente, alguém sabe me dizer se é possível? Procurei pela internet mas não achei nenhum conteúdo de fácil explicação.

Comment: Você quer forçar um `git pull` nos servidores dos clientes, é isso?

Comment: Também gostaria de saber como faço isso, pois tenho um servidor de um cliente com o site dele e queria saber se é possivel vincular o site a um repositorio git...

Comment: Como você não específicou o que você pesquisou, começe procurando por estratégias de deploy com git, e os triggers do git, principalmente o post-update. Por ser algo bem amplo, explique melhor o que deseja: localização do repositório central, dos servidores clientes, está tudo na mesma rede ou em redes separadas, etc.

Comment: Utilizar git em servidores de produção não é uma boa prática, o melhor é implementar um processo de deploy.
Referência: http://www.jamiembrown.com/blog/one-in-every-600-websites-has-git-exposed/

Comment: Isso aqui deve te ajudar: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/automatizando-a-instalacao-deploy-e-atualizacao-de-sites-com-git